# Caption in Figure only partially centered

Tags: floats, captions, minipage

I have two figures next to one another and I want to centre my Figure caption, but completely, i.e. to include Figure x.x: in centering.

This is the code I'm using:

```
\begin{figure}[!tbph]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{images/pie_chart_mobile.png}
        \caption{Frequency of playing mobile video games}
        \label{fig:pie_chart_mobile}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{images/pie_chart_multiplayer.png}
        \caption{Preference regarding multiplayer games}
        \label{fig:pie_chart_multiplayer}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

What I actually want to have is this:

[image]

I tried the `justification=centering` on the `caption` package, didn't help. Any ideas?

EDIT:
MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook} % one-sided

\PassOptionsToPackage{table,svgnames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  url=false,
  style=alphabetic,
  maxnames=4,
  minnames=3,
  maxbibnames=99,
  firstinits,
  uniquename=init]{biblatex} % TODO: adapt bibliography style
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!tbph]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{images/pie_chart_mobile.png}
        \caption{Frequency of playing mobile video games}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{images/pie_chart_multiplayer.png}
        \caption{Preference regarding multiplayer games}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: From the images it seems as if you are using the option `format=hang` of the `caption` package, in addition to the `justification=centering` option. Remove the `format=hang`, and you should get the desired output.

Comment: I am not using this option, or any other option of the `caption` package. As I already wrote, I tried `justification=centering`, but it did not help, which means I'm probably somehow overwriting it, but I do not know how. So any ideas on that?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: @Banana a more useful edit would have made a complete document that showed the problem, with all packages removed that were not needed in the example.

Comment: Done as instructed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the caption indent to `0pt` and the format to `\centering` as in the following in KOMA-Script:

```
\setcapindent{0pt}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\centering}
```

Thus, the following should work:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}

\documentclass[headsepline,footsepline,footinclude=false,oneside,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook} % one-sided

\PassOptionsToPackage{table,svgnames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  url=false,
  style=alphabetic,
  maxnames=4,
  minnames=3,
  maxbibnames=99,
  firstinits,
  uniquename=init]{biblatex} % TODO: adapt bibliography style
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

% The fix:
\setcapindent{0pt}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\centering}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/pie_chart_mobile.png}
        \caption{Frequency of playing mobile video games}
        \label{fig:pie_chart_mobile}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/pie_chart_multiplayer.png}
        \caption{Preference regarding multiplayer games}
        \label{fig:pie_chart_multiplayer}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

### Package `caption`

Package `caption` with option `justification=centering` helps usually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo only because of missing images
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!tbph]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/pie_chart_mobile.png}
        \caption{Frequency of playing mobile video games}
        \label{fig:pie_chart_mobile}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/pie_chart_multiplayer.png}
        \caption{Preference regarding multiplayer games}
        \label{fig:pie_chart_multiplayer}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Class KOMA-Script

See [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262485/16967) of nordev.

### Class `memoir`

Class `memoir` provides `\captionstyle`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo only because of missing images
\captionstyle{\centering}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!tbph]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/pie_chart_mobile.png}
        \caption{Frequency of playing mobile video games}
        \label{fig:pie_chart_mobile}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/pie_chart_multiplayer.png}
        \caption{Preference regarding multiplayer games}
        \label{fig:pie_chart_multiplayer}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: As I already wrote, I tried `justification=centering`, but it did not help, which means I'm probably somehow overwriting it, but I do not know how. So any ideas on that?

Comment: @Banana make a complete document as Heiko has done here that shows the captions _not_ centred, then someone can easily tell you why it is not working.

Comment: Done as instructed :)